# what does 'old' mean in the output of `who -u`?

Tags: linux, users

In the listings of `who -u`, some of the records show the string "old" in the idle time column.  I know that "." means the session is not idle.  What's the meaning of "old"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `info coreutils 'who invocation'`:

```
`-u'
     After the login time, print the number of hours and minutes that
     the user has been idle.  `.' means the user was active in the last
     minute.  `old' means the user has been idle for more than 24 hours.
```

**info** documentation of *GNU* tools is usually far more complete than **man** pages.

Comment: That's an important tip that I often forget (the level of detail to the `info` documentation relative the man pages).